# take ping test average change output

Tags: bash, awk

Here is my script I wanto change out put second one:

```
#!/bin/bash    

declare -a arr=("8.8.8.8" "8.8.4.4" "192.168.1.28")    
x=0    
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`     

echo $DATE > denemesh.txt

while [ $x -le 2 ]    
do    
    echo "  ${arr[x]}" >> denemesh.txt    
    ping -c 4 ${arr[x]} | tail -1| awk ' {print $4  }' | cut -d '/' -f 2 >> denemesh.txt
    x=$(( $x + 1 ))    
done
```

Currently, the output looks like this:

```
2014-12-22:20:22:37    
  8.8.8.8    
18.431    
  8.8.4.4    
17.758    
  192.168.1.28    
0.058
```

Is it possible to change to output to look like this instead?

```
2014-12-22:20:22:37    
  8.8.8.8          18.431    
  8.8.4.4          17.758    
  192.168.1.28      0.058
```

Comment: You should try to avoid using old and outdated back-tics, use parentheses instead like this: `DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really just need to modify one line:

```
echo -n "  ${arr[x]}" >> denemesh.txt
```

Using the `-n` flag suppresses the trailing newline, and so your next statement should append to the current line. You can then adjust the formatting as you please.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is. Try something like this:

```
declare -a arr=("8.8.8.8" "8.8.4.4" "192.168.1.28")    
d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S)

echo "$d" > denemesh.txt

for ip in "${arr[@]}"
do    
    printf '  %-12s' "$ip"
    ping -c 4 "$ip" | awk 'END{split($4,a,"/"); printf "%12s\n", a[2]}'
done >> denemesh.txt
```

I've used `printf` with format specifiers to align the output. The `%-12s` left-aligns the first column with a fixed width of 12 characters and the `%12s` in awk right-aligns the second column. Rather than use a `while` loop, I got rid of your variable `x` and have looped through the values in the array directly. I have also changed the old-fashioned backtick syntax in your script to use `$( )` instead. awk is capable of obtaining the output directly by itself, so I removed your usage of tail and cut too. Finally, you can simply redirect the output of the loop rather than putting `>>` on the end of each line.